# How is the speed of a bridge set?

Tags: networking, interface, network-bridge, download-speed

I have a bridge (created via `systemd-networkd`) which links a few physical interfaces. All of the interfaces are 1 Gbps, except one which is 100 Mbps.

The problem: it looks like (from local `iperf3` tests) that the speed between the bridge and a 1 Gbps device (connected through a 1 Gbps physical NIC via  a cable) is 100 Mbps.

`ethtool` shows that all of the 1000 interfaces advertise being capable of 1000 and actually negotiated 1000. The 100 interface negotiated 100.

Before going further in investigations: **how is the speed of a bridge set up?** **Specifically: is is capped to the slowest (capabilities/negotiated speed-wise) NIC?**

Comment: Yes it is capped to the slowest device. That is why almost all uses switches these day, they are capable of communicating with different devises at different speeds - Bridges default to the slowest device, thereby bringing the whole net down  - If you have a network printer, try hooking it up - and behold NEW speed of only 10 Mbps ( printers are slow devices !)

Comment: Try creating a second bridge to the 100Mbps interface, and remove the 100Mbps interface from the first bridge. See if that improves speed to the 1G interfaces.